# How to fix MySQL "Got an error reading communication packets" error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have created some PHP code for my website to call a stored procedure in my database. This will get text from a table so that I can dynamically update the text on the web page without modifying it in code.

This part works very well so far. However, When I open the MySQL error log I see the following message printed:

> Aborted connection 161 to db: 'dbname' user: 'username' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)

I have checked the firewall, which is inactive.
I have attempted using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost in the PHP code.
I have cleared the results using "mysqli_free_result($result);", this did seem to remove one of the two errors I got per query.
I have checked the max allowed packet size, which is 16M.
I have un-commented the extension mysqli in the php.ini file.

PHP:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password ";
$dbname = "dbname";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "Call StoredProcedure('primarykey',@OutValue);";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo $row["ColumnHeader"];
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

mysqli_free_result($result);

$t_id = mysqli_thread_id($conn);
mysqli_kill($conn,$t_id);
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

SQL:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`username`@`hostname` PROCEDURE `StoredProcedure`(IN PrimaryKey
VARCHAR(50), OUT Result VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN

start transaction;
select ColumnName
from dbname.tablename
where PrimaryKeyColumn = PrimaryKey;
commit;

END
```

As I mentioned, I am getting the expected result from my query and it is perfectly functional, so I am not sure what can be the cause.
The server is running MySQL version 5.7.27-0ubuntu0.18.04.1((ubuntu)). Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Update - 11/Sep/2019:

I have attempted to check how long the execution of the my PHP script takes. To do this I added the following code borrowed from this thread:
[Tracking the script execution time in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/535020/tracking-the-script-execution-time-in-php).

```
// Script start
$rustart = getrusage();

// Code ...

// Script end
function rutime($ru, $rus, $index) {
    return ($ru["ru_$index.tv_sec"]*1000 + intval($ru["ru_$index.tv_usec"]/1000))
     -  ($rus["ru_$index.tv_sec"]*1000 + intval($rus["ru_$index.tv_usec"]/1000));
}

$ru = getrusage();
echo "This process used " . rutime($ru, $rustart, "utime") .
    " ms for its computations\n";
echo "It spent " . rutime($ru, $rustart, "stime") .
    " ms in system calls\n";
```

However, the result was the following:

> This process used 0 ms for its computations It spent 1 ms in system calls

Which should not cause any timeouts.

I also activated the general log file on the server and i did see that the it would track the query as follows:

> Command Type, Detail
>
> Connect, username@hostname on dbname using Socket
>
> Query, Call StoredProcedure('PrimaryKey', @result)

I am curious about there being no log saying disconnect though I do not know if this is default behaviour from MySQL.

Another curious thing I discovered was that MySQL Workbench states my query time for the stored procedure is on average 7ms but all resources I could find states that PHP waits for the query to finish before continuing.

> Query, Total Time, Max Time, Avg Time
>
> CALL StoredProcedure ( username @ hostname ) , 98.94, 66.26, 7.07

In short, I still have not found any solutions to the issue, but potentially some leads that could eventually lead to a resolution.

Update - 18/Sep/2019:

After more digging on the issue I've come across the following thread:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/144773/mysql-aborted-connection-got-an-error-reading-communication-packets

It is suggesting that due to MySQL and PHP being installed on the same server, they are competing for RAM. Considering my server is running on a Raspberry Pi 3 model B, this seems like a plausible explanation for the issue I am facing.

Comment: Why do you `mysqli_kill` the connection?

Comment: I was thinking that the connection might not be closed properly from the php code, and so I came across this thread that suggested to use it:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879500/mysqli-do-i-really-need-to-do-result-close-mysqli-close

Comment: In my case it was a lack of memory causing this problem. I'm using Docker on macOS with [colima](https://github.com/abiosoft/colima), which assigns 2GiB RAM to its VM by default. My PHP app generally worked fine, but generating a large Excel report would fail inconsistently. All the usual advice for this error didn't help. Increasing the VM's RAM fixed it.